# laravel blade concatenate youtube iframe with variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

in my blade i want to concatenate a variable in blade iframe youtube video id from my api.

this is the code  i have done. but not working, displaying error undefined index QRfj1VCg16Y.

```
   <iframe width="580" height="360" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{$movie['QRfj1VCg16Y']}}'> 
    </iframe>
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory... Your `$movie` variable does not have an index `'QRfj1VCg16Y'`.

Comment: @TimLewis i know but that video id is in $movie variable array. but when i concatenate in the iframe it is not working.

Comment: *"that video id is in $movie variable array"* - No, it isn't, read your error: **Undefined index**. Do a `dd(isset($movie['QRfj1VCg16Y']))`, it'll say `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QRfj1VCg16Y` is the id of the video, not an index of your array:

```html
<iframe width="580" height="360" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/QRfj1VCg16Y'> 
</iframe>
```

Comment: yeah i know it is the id of the video, but that id is in $movie array, so it should be ` <iframe width="580" height="360" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/'{{ $movie['QRfj1VCg16Y'> 
</iframe>`

Comment: It's not an index of your array. Read your error message: `undefined index QRfj1VCg16Y.`

Comment: yeah i got it. i was doing wrong, i was indexing the actual video id. not the index. i already accepted your answer. thanks

Answer (score -1):

yeah. i found the solution i was inserting the actual video id not the index the api iam consuming says like this

```
"yt_trailer_code" => "QRfj1VCg16Y"
```

so the actual id is

```
$movie['yt_trailer_code']
```

that was easy. i donot know what was wrong with me